# trouble understanding the edit styles section of template manager in joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

it seems the developers fail at explaining what this page should be about

phcprotostar is a 1:1 copy of protostar (except the added 'phc' letters).

see my screenshot:

[image]

what is this page about?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What is the actual problem here?

Comment: haha your comment actually confused me as well. Can you eventually elaborate what this screen is good for? It is quite possible that I landed in the wrong menu assignment, joomla seems to have several of those

Comment: :) .. This page is so that you can assign the template to a specific page. For a little more info, have a look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_template_to_a_specific_page%3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This screen is the template manager styles tab, rather than the template tab.  A template can have as many styles as you like, you can then apply the styles to menu items as required.

An example of this is that you could copy the "protostar - Default" style to a new style called "protostar - News".  You could then apply the "protostar - News" style to the news section of your site.  This would enable you to adjust the settings in the "Advanced" tab for "protostar - News", and, for example, make the main or background color different, set a different logo, font or title.

So, in practice, a template style is a child of a template, allowing you to configure the template's style settings in different ways on different pages.

What is adjustable in the template style varies a lot from one template to the next, but in Protostar you can set:

- Template Colour
- Background Colour
- Logo
- Title
- Description
- Google Font for Headings
- Google Font Name
- Fluid Layout

The Joomla documentation for this is at...

http://docs.joomla.org/Help31:Extensions_Template_Manager_Styles

...where it gives the description...

> The Template Manager: Styles screen was introduced in Joomla! 1.6. It
>   allows you to manage template styles which you can then apply to your
>   Joomla! installation. You can specify the default style to be applied
>   to web pages in the public and administrator interfaces. You can also
>   configure different styles for the various menu item web pages on your
>   site. Styles allow to you have multiple different configurations of a
>   template saved and then apply them on a site-wide or per-page basis.